# Calcular porcentaje de numeros mas repetidos mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un pequeño problema. Estoy intentando mostrar en un en un rango de fecha, cuales son los numeros que mas se repiten, por ejemplo, en mi base de datos tengo cadenas de texto con numeros separados por comas Ej. 1,2,3,4,5,6, hasta 6 diferentes por dia.

Estoy tratando de hacer un script que me retorne cuales numeros se han repetido mas en cada posicion con su respectivo porcentaje. Hasta ahora pude hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    // CUENTO EL TOTAL DE REGISTROS EN LA TABLA
    $total = $cnn->query("SELECT count($type) as Total FROM tabla WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$desde' and '$hasta");
$res_total = $total->fetch_assoc();
// AGRUPO EL NUMERO
$hot = $cnn->query("SELECT count($type) as Total FROM tabla WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$desde' and '$hasta' GROUP BY $type ORDER BY Total DESC LIMIT 1");
$res_hot = $hot->fetch_assoc();
$pct = round(($res_hot[Total] / $res_total[Total]) * 100);
echo $res_hot[$type].' - '.$pct.'%'.'<br>';
```

Esto me devuelve algo como esto:

```
4,5,1,0,4,6 - 5%
```

Quiere decir que el numero 4,5,1,0,4,6 fue el que mas se repitio pero lo que me interesa es saber cual de los numeros fueron los que mas se repitieron por separado.

Por ejemplo 4 10%, 5 3% , etc etc

Se ve mas o menos asi mi base de datos

```
2019-01-01  4,3,4,5,7,0
2019-01-01  7,4,4,8,7,3
2019-01-01  3,6,5,9,5,9
2019-01-01  0,6,5,4,2,4
2019-01-01  5,8,0,0,3,8
2019-01-01  2,2,9,4,0,5
2019-01-01  9,2,8,3,5,3
2019-01-02  4,1,8,8,4,1
2019-01-02  1,7,4,4,6,9
2019-01-02  3,3,5,2,9,0
2019-01-02  4,6,5,4,3,6
2019-01-02  9,3,6,9,3,5
2019-01-02  2,0,0,6,4,1
2019-01-02  4,2,4,6,7,3
2019-01-03  1,6,1,5,9,1
2019-01-03  5,0,3,7,1,6
2019-01-03  3,6,5,2,7,0
2019-01-03  2,7,1,7,2,4
2019-01-03  9,1,7,1,8,7
```

Ojala me pudieran dar alguna idea.